# what are the coding guidelines of J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, coding-style

hi I googled but could not come up with good links for J2ME coding guidelines.Can you guys share some pointers for the same.Please share the best coding practices to be used ..please don't replicate java code guidelines.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additionally to following standards I'd mention the following. Although modern phones a relatively strong computers some CPU and memory limitations still exist. So,

- avoid using deep inheritance
- do not use verbose patterns like visitor, factory etc
- use interfaces only when you need. Use abstract classes instead.
- Use factory methods implemented in abstract base classes.
- do not use inner classes. If you need several event handlers make the class itself to implement the needed interface and use if/else code into this handler method to understand the event's source. Bad design but saves a lot of space. :(
- use pre-processing.
- obfuscate your code. It saves up to 40% of size.

etc, etc...

Comment: I would like to add some : 1. Try to minimize method;s code 2.save memory as you are saving your breath when you have only last 5 breath for life :)

Comment: Jigar..;)..would keep this in mind